# Problemas de framework boostrap con datableboostrap en .net c#

Tags: javascript, html, c#, css

Amigos tengo un problema con el link de boostrap 4 y datableboostrap.min

como podria evitar el error de las imagenes, esto solo como ejemplo el problema me da con master page pero se que al arreglar aqui funcionara en c#.

Imagen sin boostrap

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

imagen con boostrap agregado

al agregar este link `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />` y lo ocupo para la plantilla que tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>DataTables example - Bootstrap 3</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/site-examples.css?_=19472395a2969da78c8a4c707e72123a">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/site.js?_=5e8f232afab336abc1a1b65046a73460"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/dynamic.php?comments-page=examples%2Fstyling%2Fbootstrap.html" async></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../resources/demo.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/i18n/Spanish.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();

} );

    </script>
</head>

<body>

                <table id="example" class="table  table-striped table-bordered" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                            <td>Accountant</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>63</td>
                            <td>2011/07/25</td>
                            <td>$170,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                            <td>2009/01/12</td>
                            <td>$86,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>2012/03/29</td>
                            <td>$433,060</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Airi Satou</td>
                            <td>Accountant</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>33</td>
                            <td>2008/11/28</td>
                            <td>$162,700</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2012/12/02</td>
                            <td>$372,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>59</td>
                            <td>2012/08/06</td>
                            <td>$137,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>55</td>
                            <td>2010/10/14</td>
                            <td>$327,900</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>39</td>
                            <td>2009/09/15</td>
                            <td>$205,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>2008/12/13</td>
                            <td>$103,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>2008/12/19</td>
                            <td>$90,560</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                            <td>Support Lead</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>2013/03/03</td>
                            <td>$342,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>36</td>
                            <td>2008/10/16</td>
                            <td>$470,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>43</td>
                            <td>2012/12/18</td>
                            <td>$313,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>19</td>
                            <td>2010/03/17</td>
                            <td>$385,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Michael Silva</td>
                            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                            <td>2012/11/27</td>
                            <td>$198,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                            <td>2010/06/09</td>
                            <td>$725,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gloria Little</td>
                            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>59</td>
                            <td>2009/04/10</td>
                            <td>$237,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>41</td>
                            <td>2012/10/13</td>
                            <td>$132,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Dai Rios</td>
                            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>35</td>
                            <td>2012/09/26</td>
                            <td>$217,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                            <td>Development Lead</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>2011/09/03</td>
                            <td>$345,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>40</td>
                            <td>2009/06/25</td>
                            <td>$675,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>2011/12/12</td>
                            <td>$106,450</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                            <td>Sidney</td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>2010/09/20</td>
                            <td>$85,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2009/10/09</td>
                            <td>$1,200,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>42</td>
                            <td>2010/12/22</td>
                            <td>$92,575</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>28</td>
                            <td>2010/11/14</td>
                            <td>$357,650</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>28</td>
                            <td>2011/06/07</td>
                            <td>$206,850</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fiona Green</td>
                            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>48</td>
                            <td>2010/03/11</td>
                            <td>$850,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shou Itou</td>
                            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>2011/08/14</td>
                            <td>$163,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Michelle House</td>
                            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                            <td>Sidney</td>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>2011/06/02</td>
                            <td>$95,400</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Suki Burks</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>53</td>
                            <td>2009/10/22</td>
                            <td>$114,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                            <td>Technical Author</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                            <td>2011/05/07</td>
                            <td>$145,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                            <td>Team Leader</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>2008/10/26</td>
                            <td>$235,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>46</td>
                            <td>2011/03/09</td>
                            <td>$324,050</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Unity Butler</td>
                            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2009/12/09</td>
                            <td>$85,675</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>51</td>
                            <td>2008/12/16</td>
                            <td>$164,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                            <td>Secretary</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>41</td>
                            <td>2010/02/12</td>
                            <td>$109,850</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                            <td>Financial Controller</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>62</td>
                            <td>2009/02/14</td>
                            <td>$452,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>2008/12/11</td>
                            <td>$136,200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                            <td>Director</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>65</td>
                            <td>2008/09/26</td>
                            <td>$645,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                            <td>Support Engineer</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                            <td>2011/02/03</td>
                            <td>$234,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>38</td>
                            <td>2011/05/03</td>
                            <td>$163,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                            <td>Support Engineer</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>2009/08/19</td>
                            <td>$139,575</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Thor Walton</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2013/08/11</td>
                            <td>$98,540</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                            <td>Support Engineer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2009/07/07</td>
                            <td>$87,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                            <td>2012/04/09</td>
                            <td>$138,575</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>63</td>
                            <td>2010/01/04</td>
                            <td>$125,250</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>56</td>
                            <td>2012/06/01</td>
                            <td>$115,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>43</td>
                            <td>2013/02/01</td>
                            <td>$75,650</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>46</td>
                            <td>2011/12/06</td>
                            <td>$145,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2011/03/21</td>
                            <td>$356,250</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Lael Greer</td>
                            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>2009/02/27</td>
                            <td>$103,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>2010/07/14</td>
                            <td>$86,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shad Decker</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>51</td>
                            <td>2008/11/13</td>
                            <td>$183,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>29</td>
                            <td>2011/06/27</td>
                            <td>$183,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Donna Snider</td>
                            <td>Customer Support</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                            <td>2011/01/25</td>
                            <td>$112,000</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de arreglarlo es agregando el estilo `display: block` al wrapper asi:

```css
.dataTables_wrapper.form-inline {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>DataTables example - Bootstrap 3</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/media/images/favicon.png">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();

} );

    </script>
</head>

<body>

                <table id="example" class="table  table-striped table-bordered" >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                            <td>System Architect</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2011/04/25</td>
                            <td>$320,800</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                            <td>Accountant</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>63</td>
                            <td>2011/07/25</td>
                            <td>$170,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                            <td>2009/01/12</td>
                            <td>$86,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>2012/03/29</td>
                            <td>$433,060</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Airi Satou</td>
                            <td>Accountant</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>33</td>
                            <td>2008/11/28</td>
                            <td>$162,700</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2012/12/02</td>
                            <td>$372,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>59</td>
                            <td>2012/08/06</td>
                            <td>$137,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>55</td>
                            <td>2010/10/14</td>
                            <td>$327,900</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>39</td>
                            <td>2009/09/15</td>
                            <td>$205,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>2008/12/13</td>
                            <td>$103,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>2008/12/19</td>
                            <td>$90,560</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                            <td>Support Lead</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>2013/03/03</td>
                            <td>$342,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>36</td>
                            <td>2008/10/16</td>
                            <td>$470,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>43</td>
                            <td>2012/12/18</td>
                            <td>$313,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>19</td>
                            <td>2010/03/17</td>
                            <td>$385,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Michael Silva</td>
                            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>66</td>
                            <td>2012/11/27</td>
                            <td>$198,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                            <td>2010/06/09</td>
                            <td>$725,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gloria Little</td>
                            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>59</td>
                            <td>2009/04/10</td>
                            <td>$237,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>41</td>
                            <td>2012/10/13</td>
                            <td>$132,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Dai Rios</td>
                            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>35</td>
                            <td>2012/09/26</td>
                            <td>$217,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                            <td>Development Lead</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>2011/09/03</td>
                            <td>$345,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>40</td>
                            <td>2009/06/25</td>
                            <td>$675,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>2011/12/12</td>
                            <td>$106,450</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                            <td>Sidney</td>
                            <td>23</td>
                            <td>2010/09/20</td>
                            <td>$85,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2009/10/09</td>
                            <td>$1,200,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>42</td>
                            <td>2010/12/22</td>
                            <td>$92,575</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>28</td>
                            <td>2010/11/14</td>
                            <td>$357,650</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>28</td>
                            <td>2011/06/07</td>
                            <td>$206,850</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fiona Green</td>
                            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>48</td>
                            <td>2010/03/11</td>
                            <td>$850,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shou Itou</td>
                            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                            <td>2011/08/14</td>
                            <td>$163,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Michelle House</td>
                            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                            <td>Sidney</td>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>2011/06/02</td>
                            <td>$95,400</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Suki Burks</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>53</td>
                            <td>2009/10/22</td>
                            <td>$114,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                            <td>Technical Author</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                            <td>2011/05/07</td>
                            <td>$145,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                            <td>Team Leader</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>22</td>
                            <td>2008/10/26</td>
                            <td>$235,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>46</td>
                            <td>2011/03/09</td>
                            <td>$324,050</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Unity Butler</td>
                            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2009/12/09</td>
                            <td>$85,675</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>51</td>
                            <td>2008/12/16</td>
                            <td>$164,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                            <td>Secretary</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>41</td>
                            <td>2010/02/12</td>
                            <td>$109,850</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                            <td>Financial Controller</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>62</td>
                            <td>2009/02/14</td>
                            <td>$452,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                            <td>Office Manager</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>2008/12/11</td>
                            <td>$136,200</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                            <td>Director</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>65</td>
                            <td>2008/09/26</td>
                            <td>$645,750</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                            <td>Support Engineer</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                            <td>2011/02/03</td>
                            <td>$234,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>38</td>
                            <td>2011/05/03</td>
                            <td>$163,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                            <td>Support Engineer</td>
                            <td>Tokyo</td>
                            <td>37</td>
                            <td>2009/08/19</td>
                            <td>$139,575</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Thor Walton</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>61</td>
                            <td>2013/08/11</td>
                            <td>$98,540</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                            <td>Support Engineer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2009/07/07</td>
                            <td>$87,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                            <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>64</td>
                            <td>2012/04/09</td>
                            <td>$138,575</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>63</td>
                            <td>2010/01/04</td>
                            <td>$125,250</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                            <td>Software Engineer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>56</td>
                            <td>2012/06/01</td>
                            <td>$115,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                            <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>43</td>
                            <td>2013/02/01</td>
                            <td>$75,650</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>46</td>
                            <td>2011/12/06</td>
                            <td>$145,600</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>47</td>
                            <td>2011/03/21</td>
                            <td>$356,250</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Lael Greer</td>
                            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                            <td>London</td>
                            <td>21</td>
                            <td>2009/02/27</td>
                            <td>$103,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                            <td>Developer</td>
                            <td>San Francisco</td>
                            <td>30</td>
                            <td>2010/07/14</td>
                            <td>$86,500</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Shad Decker</td>
                            <td>Regional Director</td>
                            <td>Edinburgh</td>
                            <td>51</td>
                            <td>2008/11/13</td>
                            <td>$183,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                            <td>Singapore</td>
                            <td>29</td>
                            <td>2011/06/27</td>
                            <td>$183,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Donna Snider</td>
                            <td>Customer Support</td>
                            <td>New York</td>
                            <td>27</td>
                            <td>2011/01/25</td>
                            <td>$112,000</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Me ayuda a la distorsion que tenia excelente pero cuando la paso a la master page en visual me omite la barra de abajo(scroll, si aparece la vertical pero no la horizontal )  cuando la hago responsive podrias ayudarme.... Gracias